# Rename files with specific pattern and trimming the rest of the name - bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have my files with the below names, I am trying to get rid of the unwanted chars and just want to get the file name alone extracted.

File names

```
          abc_xyz.file name 1.unwanted part.xls
          abc_xyz.file 2.unwanted part.xls
          abc_xyz.file name 3.unwanted part.xls
          abc_xyz.file name 4.unwanted part.csv
          abc_xyz.file 5.unwanted part.csv
          abc_xyz.file name 6.unwanted part.csv
```

I want my files to be renamed which have only .xls in the extenstion and with the same name.

```
          file name 1.xls
          file 2.xls
          file name 3.xls
          abc_xyz.file name 4.unwanted part.csv
          abc_xyz.file 5.unwanted part.csv
          abc_xyz.file name 6.unwanted part.csv
```

I tried to use a for loop with sed and awk commands, but am not able to get it done. Here is what I have tried. I have saved the file names which I want to change in /tmp/dileep/files.txt and used below command to get the names that I want, into a different file.

```
          cut -d '.' -f2  < /tmp/dileep/files.txt | sed -e 's/._//g' > /tmp/dileep/names.txt
```

I am able to get the file names as what I want, but I am unable to iterate within them to rename them with the correct name.

```
for i in *.xls ; do cp $i /tmp/dileep/{awk -F '.' '{print $2}' < $i | sed -e 
's/._//g'} ; done
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'
cp: invalid option -- 'F'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'
cp: invalid option -- 'F'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
-bash: $i: ambiguous redirect
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'
-bash: $i: ambiguous redirect
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: Can you confirm that the 'unwanted part' is a fixed string you already know, or is it a variable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To handle spaces or new lines in file names try following.

```
find /tmp -type f -name "*.xls" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;
do
   new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)[^.]*\.\([^.]*\.\).*/\1\2xls/')
   echo "mv \"$file\" \"$new_file\""
done
```

Above will print commands on terminal, to run them and rename files run following once you are Happy with above.

```
find /tmp -type f -name "*.xls" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;
do
   new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)[^.]*\.\([^.]*\.\).*/\1\2xls/')
   echo "mv \"$file\" \"$new_file\"" | sh
done
```

Also with `find` I have give `/tmp` as an example, please change it to complete path as per your need too.

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
for file in *.xls
do
   new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^.]*\.\).*/\1xls/')
   echo "mv \"$file\" \"$new_file\""
done
```

As of now it is only printing `mv`(command to rename the files) on terminal once you are Happy you could run following code then.

With few shown samples output of above command will be as follows.

```
mv "abc_xyz.file 2.unwanted part.xls" "file 2.xls"
mv "abc_xyz.file name 1.unwanted part.xls" "file name 1.xls"
mv "abc_xyz.file name 3.unwanted part.xls" "file name 3.xls"
```

---

---

***Run following only and only when you are Happy with above command's result since this will rename the files.***

```
for file in *.xls
do
   new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^.]*\.\).*/\1xls/')
   echo "mv \"$file\" \"$new_file\"" | sh
done
```

Comment: The for loop will not work correctly when the file names contain spaces.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, I just tested and it worked, but lemme add some more as precautionary code, cheers.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, Added an EDIT code now, to take care of file names more carefully, could you please do lemme know if this looks ok to you now?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the file where the 'unwanted part' must be stripped from is `/tmp/dileep/files.txt`, the only thing you have to do is:

```
sed -i -e '/\.xls$/s/^abc_xyz\.//' -e 's/unwanted part\.xls/.xls/' /tmp/dileep/files.txt
```

The option `-i` means you make the change inside the file `/tmp/dileep/files.txt`.

Please clarify how to know which is the unwanted part.

Answer (score 0):

Use rename, it provides lot of option for rule based rename, for the specific case, regular expression substitution seems like the approach

```
rename 's/\.unwanted part\././' file-list

# Bulk, wildcard
rename 's/\.unwanted part\././' file-list *".unwanted part."*
```

Use `rename -n` ... test the translation to avoid errors. The 'man rename' and 'info rename' can provide more information.

Note: there are multiple rename programs. On some systems, you will have to invoke the correct alternative with 'file-rename'.

Note 2: Remember to property quote the files - as they have embedded spaces